# What is wrong with below code

Tags: c

The code was suppose to rotate a one-dimensional vector of n elements left by i position. for instance, with n=8 and i = 3, the vector abcdefgh is rotated to defghabc.

The below crashes at string_reverse function. couldn't find out what's wrong there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include < conio.h>

void string_reverse(char* str, int left, int right )
{
    char *p1 = str + left;
    char *p2 = str + right;

    while (p1 < p2) 
    {
        char temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = temp;
        p1++;
        p2--;
    }
}


void rotate( char* str, int k )
{
    int n = strlen( str );
    string_reverse( str, 0, k - 1 );
    string_reverse( str, k, n - 1 );
    string_reverse( str, 0, n -1 );
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* string = "abcdefghijk";

    rotate( string, 3 );    
    printf("%s",string );   
    getch();
    return 0;
}



it crashes at 

*p1 = *p2;
```

Comment: How does it crash, what compiler did you use and what platform are you running on?

Comment: What do you mean "it crashed". Was it a segmentation fault?

Comment: This proves that it is a good practice to declare `char *` as `const` when assigning to a literal.

Comment: @Joe On my compiler, that only causes a compiler warning, not an error.

Comment: @MrLister do you ignore compiler warnings?

Comment: @Joe I don't, but you never know with beginners.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
char* string = "abcdefghijk";
```

to

```
char string[] = "abcdefghijk"
```

The former points to a read-only string literal, whereas the later is an array initialized from that literal.

Comment: What do you mean by read-only literal? Why compiler treats it as read-only?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's what it means. It is actually part of the compiled C program, so you can't change it. If you could, that would mean changing the executable code itself, which is not a good idea. E.G. you wouldn't be able to put this program in ROM. Things like that.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a string to manipulate on, use a real character array rather than a character pointer.

```
    char string[] = "abcdefghijk";
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocated as a variable initializer, like this...

```
char* string = "abcdefghijk";
```

...is immutable.  That is, you can't change it, and attempts to write to it will result in a segfault.  You can only modify memory allocated via `malloc()` and friends.  You can accomplish this very easily with your static string like this:

```
char *string = strdup("abcdefghijk");
```

The `strdup()` function calls `malloc()` internally and then copies the source string into the target.  You're already `#include`-ing `string.h`, so the `strdup()` function prototype is already available without any additional code.

Comment: Note that `strdup()` is non-standard.

Comment: And this causes a memory leak.

Comment: It sure did.  Thanks for playing.

Comment: Jonathan -- `strdup()` is pretty standard.  According to the man page: `strdup() conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.`

Comment: Although well known it is not part of the standard in C89,C99 or C11 though. With that said you would likely be safe using it.